# Kubernetes - create secret with a label using cli in a single line

Tags: kubernetes

I can create a secret using a single line command like so:

```
kubectl -n myns create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=type=super --from-literal=url=example.com --from-file=samples=sample.txt
```

But it's missing a label when this is created. I want to keep it as a single line command.

Can I pass in a label parameter or do i need to do a second call to modify the created secret?

Comment: `kubectl create` subcommand does not have any `-l` flag present. this means you cannot label it during the time of creation if used imperatively.  you got two options, use manifest file or heredoc, or use `&&` operator to first create the secret and then label it. note that `kubectl run` subcommand does have `-l` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an option in the `kubectl create secret` command to add a label.

You will need to run a second command to add the label:

```bash
kubectl label secret my-secret -n myns "foo=bar"
```

But you could technically do it on one line like:

```bash
kubectl create secret generic my-secret ... && kubectl label secret my-secret "foo=bar"
```

Or do as [@larsks suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467037/2446208) which is much better for job security.

Comment: I like readability better. I wonder why they didn't add a labels param.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on your definition of "in a single line". Here's a single line:

```
$ kubectl -n myns create secret generic my-secret \
    --from-literal=type=super \
    --from-literal=url=example.com \
    --from-file=samples=sample.txt -o json --dry-run=client |
 jq '.metadata.labels |= {"foo":"bar"}' |
 kubectl apply -f-
```

We create the secret, send it as JSON to stdout, modify the JSON using `jq`, and then pipe the result into `kubectl apply -f-`.

The output of the first two commands is:

```
{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "my-secret",
    "namespace": "myns",
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "samples": "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QK",
    "type": "c3VwZXI=",
    "url": "ZXhhbXBsZS5jb20="
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have rephrased my question "in a single call". Points for creative use of jq and fancy `-f-`

Comment: what about RBAC? here you need "patch" or "create" is fine ?